# Nested explicit StyleDefinitions not working

Tags: bugs, output-formatting, formatting, stylesheet

### Bug introduced in 10.0.2 or earlier and persists through 11.3

> [CASE:4061425], confirmed

### TL;DR;

How can I add a style definition to a notebook with existing, arbitrary `StyleDefinitions` already set?

### Full question, my attempt

Consider the following two example notebooks:

```
NotebookPut@Notebook[
  {Cell["abc", "Text"]},
  StyleDefinitions -> Notebook@{
     Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"]],
     Cell[StyleData["Text"], FontColor -> Green]
     }
  ]

NotebookPut@Notebook[
  {Cell["abc", "Text"]},
  StyleDefinitions -> Notebook@{
     Cell[StyleData[
       StyleDefinitions -> Notebook@{
          Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"]],
          Cell[StyleData["Text"], FontColor -> Green]
          }
       ]],
     Cell[StyleData["Text"], FontSize -> 40]
     }
  ]
```

The first one has `StyleDefinitions` set which override the `FontColor` of `"Text"` style cells to be `Green`, and inherit the rest from `"Default.nb"`. The second one has `StyleDefinitions` inheriting the ones from the previous example, and overrides the `FontSize` of `"Text"` style cells.

This yields:

[image: abc green]

and

[image: abc big]

Clearly, the second example is not what's expected. Looking at the stylesheet (of the second notebook) shows the following:

[image: Unkown StyleData syntax]

*The question is*: why is this not working?

### Checking the docs

Looking at the documentation of [`StyleData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StyleData.html) (Details, point 6):

> - Parent stylesheets are defined by a style cell with the form `StyleData[StyleDefinitions -> stylesheet]`, where *stylesheet* can take any of the forms allowed for the [`StyleDefinitions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StyleDefinitions.html) option at the notebook level.

And the referenced documentation for [`StyleDefinitions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StyleDefinitions.html) reads:

> - `StyleDefinitions->"name.nb"` specifies that style definitions from the notebook `"name.nb"` should be used.
> - ...
> - `StyleDefinitions->Notebook[…]` allows style definitions to be given explicitly.

For me, this means that I can nest `StyleDefinitions` arbitrarily, mixing `"name.nb"` specifications and `Notebook[…]` type specifications without any restrictions.

### And finally

Is this a bug? Am I missing something? Is there a way to wrap an existing style sheet, no matter whether it is a notebook, or a `Notebook[…]`? Specifically, this came up since I need to temporarily change a few style definitions in a notebook that already has a `Notebook[…]` type style sheet set.

Comment: Please report this unless you already did.

Comment: The `StyleData` reference page is in error.  `StyleDefinitions->Notebook[]` cannot be used in that context.

Comment: @ihojnicki So it is not supposed to work? That's a shame… Would be nice to have a uniform way to wrap StyleDefinitions

Comment: @Mathe172 I'm certainly open to the idea of extending it.